# Repetition in Stack Apps user of the month

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

My profile is repeated in top Stack Apps users of the month as shown in the snapshot.[image]

Is it normal?

Comment: This got nothing to do with stack apps. It "happens" with all sites in the reputation leagues.

Comment: I wasn't knowing. I got such position in Stack Apps hence highlighted the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are logged in, the first line always shows you (currently logged in user), then you see all the other rankings, which includes you, and if you had quite a high rank, you'll see yourself again.

For example, that's how I see the same leagues:

> [image]

And if I logout, there's no current user, so the ranking will look like this:

> [image]

Comment: Wait... why does my username show in the second image but not the first?? Are they different computers!?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes, different computers :) Just in case I have loads of them, all are ready to use in any time. So I accidentally took two screenshots on different computers :D

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ You know, I live in the castle in [Arendelle](http://disney.wikia.com/wiki/Arendelle) and being the sister of the Queen Elsa, so having multiple computers is a non-issue!

Comment: I've been meaning to watch Frozen for quite a while... might do this weekend! :p

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ Yes, do it! It's *wonderful*, the best ever!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's normal, because it's only for you. The currently logged on user is always shown on the top, with his ranking.

Comment: I can accept only one post as answer to the question.